# Как настроить дебаг Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

При попытках дебага студия постоянно ныряет в какие-то глубины библиотек, чего нет, допустим, в `IntelliJ IDEA`, где код, как правило, прыгает только по классам, написанным разработчиком. Не знаю, с чем это связано, но это замечают многие.

Есть ли возможность настроить студию таким образом, чтобы она "прыгала" при дебаге только по классам, написанным разработчиком?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34473411/3212712) можно исключить при дебаге классы по шаблонам их именования (т.е. по пакету) так:

```
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Stepping.
```

далее ищем кнопку "Add Pattern", вбиваем нужный паттерн для исключения, например

```
android.*
```

И больше не видим при дебаге классы, которые находятся в пакете `android`

Comment: Спасибо, Юрий. Как всегда, Ваши ответы помогают решить проблему в корне.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов, пожалуйста) На самом деле я просто копирнул решение из первой ссылки выдачи гугла на запрос `android studio debug only my code` =)